# Why am I getting "Error: Resolution method is overspecified"?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

After the upgrade, Mocha can not even run a simple test here is the code

```
const assert = require('assert');

it('should complete this test', function (done) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    assert.ok(true);
    resolve();
   })
  .then(done);
});
```

I took this code from [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#boom-breaking-changes)

I understood that it now throws an exception `Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback * or * return a Promise; not both.`

But how to make it work? I did not understand. I have

```
node -v 6.9.4

mocha -v 3.2.0
```

**How to run this code are now in a new and correct format?**

Comment: overloaded, underdamped, overdetermined

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just drop
`.then(done);` and replace `function(done)` with `function()`

You are returning a Promise so calling done is redundant as it said in error message

In the elder versions you had to use callback in case of async methods like that

```
it ('returns async', function(done) {
   callAsync()
   .then(function(result) {
      assert.ok(result);
      done();
   });
})
```

Now you have an alternative of returning a Promise

```
it ('returns async', function() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
     callAsync()
       .then(function(result) {
          assert.ok(result);
          resolve();
       });
  });
})
```

But using both is misleading
(see for example here https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2407)

Answer (score 22):

Mocha allows to either use a callback:

```
it('should complete this test', function (done) {
  new Promise(function (resolve) {
    assert.ok(true);
    resolve();
   })
  .then(done);
});
```

**OR** return a promise:

```
it('should complete this test', function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    assert.ok(true);
    resolve();
   });
});

// Or in the async manner
it('should complete this test', async () => {
    await Promise.resolve();
    assert.ok(true);
});
```

You can't do both.

Comment: Another alternative: you can change `function ()` to `async function ()` and `return` to `await`. Is that accurate? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I had to removed the `done` from the function parameter and the `done()` of the function call
**Before**

```
   before(async function (done) {
        user = new User({ ...});
        await user.save();
        done()
    });
```

**After**

```
   before(async function () {
        user = new User({ ...});
        await user.save();
    });
```

These works for me

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. A lot of times Mocha is paired with another library called Chai. Chai has a package called "chai-as-promised". It gives you the super simple ability to write less code and test promises. In your case of just testing if a promise resolves, it seems perfect.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
const should = require("chai").should();
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe("Testing with correct syntax and non repeated names", () => {
    it("Should give us a positive response", () => {
      graphQL.sendToGQL(model,"specialEndpoint").should.eventually.be.an("Object");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

An example of async functions with done breaking.

**Failure Case**

```
it('If the credentials exists in the system it should return the token generated against it.', async (done) => {
    let aObj = await admin.createAdmin();
    chai.request(server)
    .post("/authenticate")
    .set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .send({username: aObj.login,password:aObj.password})
    .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a("string");
        done();
    });
});
```

**Success Case**

```
it('If the credentials exists in the system it should return the token generated against it.', async () => {
    let adminObj = await admin.createAdmin();
    chai.request(server)
    .post("/auth/login")
    .set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .send({username: adminObj.login,password:adminObj.password})
    .end((err, res) => {
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.body.should.be.a("string");
        // done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have callbacks, prior answers (which suggest deleting the `done`) is correct.

If need to **both** await some external promise, and then exercise a callback/errback-based implementation in your test, that solution doesn't help you.

You can use a library like `pify` to convert the callback API to use promises.

Alternatively, you can use a `Latch` in your callback:

```js
  it("test", async () => {
    const l = new Latch()
    const v = await promiseValue()
    s.methodThatTakesCallback((err, result) => {
      expect(result).to.eql(expected)
      l.resolve() // < notifies mocha your test is done
    })
    return l.promise
  })
```

In TypeScript, here's a very stripped-down Latch implementation:

```
/**
 * Simple one-count concurrent barrier
 */
export class Latch {
  readonly promise: Promise<void>
  resolve!: () => void
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise<void>(resolve => (this.resolve = resolve))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just emit done callback completely and use async instead.
(This implementation is based on an express api running on firebase functions, using a custom jsonwebtoken)

```
const { FIREBASE_UID } = require('dotenv').config()?.parsed
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../lib/api').API;
const should = chai.should();
const expect = chai.expect

chai.use(chaiHttp)

const test = chai.request(server).keepOpen()

// get your token with an earlier mock request and store to a var
describe('Just checking a token', () => {

 let some_token
 it('should print custom jwt for testing, status: 200'), async () => {
    try {
        const res = await test.get(`/createCustomFirebaseToken/${FIREBASE_UID}`).send()
        res.should.exist
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.should.have.json
        some_token = (JSON.parse(res.text)).token
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
 it('should print details:PING, status:200'), async () => {
    try {
        const res = await test.get('/').set('Authorization',`Bearer ${some_token}`)
                              .send()
        res.should.exist
        res.should.have.status(200);
        res.should.have.json
        const { details, status } = JSON.parse(res.text)
        expect(details).to.equal('PING')
        expect(status).to.equal(200)
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
 }
 after(() => test.close())
})
```