# getting error : Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, node-modules, chai

when i run my function it gives me error : `Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.` can anyone please check my code, and help to resolve this issue ? here i have placed my full code

```
it('Get Organizations', async function (done) {
        let user_permission = await commonService.getuserPermission(logged_in_user_id,'organizations','findAll');
        let api_status = 404;
        if(user_permission) { 
            api_status = 200;
        }

        let current_token = currentResponse['token'];
        old_unique_token = current_token;

        chai.request(app)
            .post('entities')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('vrc-access-token', current_token)
            .send({ "key": "organizations", "operation": "findAll" })
            .end(function (err, res) {
                currentResponse = res.body;
                expect(err).to.be.null;
                expect(res).to.have.status(api_status);
                done();
            }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `done` when defining an `async` unit test function, rather simply return as you normally would from an async method, after `await`ing the request from `chai-http`:

```
it('Get Organizations', async function () {
        let user_permission = await commonService.getuserPermission(logged_in_user_id,'organizations','findAll');
        let api_status = 404;
        if(user_permission) { 
            api_status = 200;
        }

        let current_token = currentResponse['token'];
        old_unique_token = current_token;

        await chai.request(app) // note 'await' here
            .post('entities')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('vrc-access-token', current_token)
            .send({ "key": "organizations", "operation": "findAll" })
            .then(function (err, res) { // not 'then', not 'end'
                currentResponse = res.body;
                expect(err).to.be.null;
                expect(res).to.have.status(api_status);
            }); 

    });
```

The test runner will `await` your function automatically.

Comment: if i don't use done(), then it gives me this error : Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called;

Comment: Ah, it seems chai.request() might require that you use `then()` instead of `end()` to return a Promise. Look at "Dealing with the response - Promises" example here: https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/

Answer (score -2):

It is an "issue" with mocha. Remove the `done()` from your code. It is redundant when using Promises like in `chai.request`.

> You are returning a Promise so calling done is redundant as it said in
>   error message
>
> In the elder versions you had to use callback in case of async methods
>   like that

```
it ('returns async', function(done) {    callAsync()   
 .then(function(result) {
       assert.ok(result);
       done();    }); })
```

> Now you have an alternative of returning a Promise

```
it ('returns async', function() {   return new Promise(function
(resolve) {
      callAsync()
        .then(function(result) {
           assert.ok(result);
           resolve();
        });   }); })
```

From: [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761683/why-am-i-getting-error-resolution-method-is-overspecified)

Comment: If done isn't used, then even negative tests pass.