# mocha user async function and done

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

This is my code

```js
it('fires change event when calling blah.doSomethingThatFiresChange', async function (done) {
  const blah = await getBlah()
  blah.on('change', () => done())
  blah.doSomethingThatFiresChange()
})
```

And I have the folowing error

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

But I am not returning any promise

If I change mu code for

```js
it('fires change event when calling blah.doSomethingThatFiresChange', async function (done) {
  const blah = await getBlah()
  //blah.on('change', () => done())
  blah.doSomethingThatFiresChange()
})
```

I have a timeout

Comment: "_But I am not returning any promise_" - Yes you do. You pass an `async function`, [which always returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value).

Comment: OK, I understand
Is there any way to handle the event result and async function in this case ?

Comment: One option could be to not use an `async function` and use the `.then()` of the value returned by `getBlah()` instead of `await`. Like `getBlah().then(blah => { blah.on('change', () => done()); blah.doSomethingThatFiresChange(); })`

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761683/why-am-i-getting-error-resolution-method-is-overspecified

Comment: Thanks, It was already done with promise before, but I would like to change for async as chalenge